# Using Goroutines for background work inside an http handler

Tags: go, goroutine

I thought I'd found an easy way to return an http response immediately then do some work in the background without blocking. However, this doesn't work.

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //handle form values
    go doSomeBackgroundWork() // this will take 2 or 3 seconds
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

It works the first time--the response is returned immediately and the background work starts. However, any further requests hang until the background goroutine completes. Is there a better way to do this, that doesn't involve setting up a message queue and a separate background process.

Comment: It was actually just a test function doing some arithmetic, but apparently you were correct. GOMAXPROCS was set to whatever the default was, apparently 1. When I upped it to 2 it works fine. Thanks--if you want to answer this, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Minor note, but you probably want `http.StatusAccepted` there instead of `http.StatusOK` – 200 implies you've serviced the request.  202 tells the client that you intend to service the request, but you've not necessarily done so yet.  204 (`http.StatusNoContent`) is also sometimes acceptable, but I probably wouldn't use it in this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go multiplexes goroutines onto the available threads which is determined by the `GOMAXPROCS` environment setting. As a result if this is set to 1 then a single goroutine can hog the single thread Go has available to it until it yields control back to the Go runtime. More than likely `doSomeBackgroundWork` is hogging all the time on a single thread which is preventing the http handler from getting scheduled.

There are a number of ways to fix this.

First, as a general rule when using goroutines, you should set `GOMAXPROCS` to the number of CPUs your system has or to whichever is bigger.

Second, you can yield control in a goroutine by doing any of the following:

- `runtime.Gosched()`
- `ch <- foo`
- `foo := <-ch`
- `select { ... }`
- `mutex.Lock()`
- `mutex.Unlock()`

All of these will yield back to the Go runtime scheduler giving other goroutines a chance to work.

Comment: Note that in development right now (in go tip) is a version of the scheduler which will preempt goroutines on any function call, not just the list above.  This is expected to land in go 1.2.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood could you link to a source? I just tried to compile Go from the development tip, then compile a program with it and the behavior looked the same.

Comment: It preempts on function *calls* not in the middle of the function so tip won't fix your particular problem yet.

Comment: @JeremyWall please check my recent post.

Answer (score 20):

I know this question was posted 4 years ago, but I hope someone can find this useful.

Here is a way to do that

There are something called worker pool https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools Using go routines and channels

But in the following code I adapt it to a handler. (Consider for simplicity I'm ignoring the errors and I'm using jobs as global variable)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var jobs chan int

func worker(jobs <-chan int) {
    fmt.Println("Register the worker")
    for i := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("worker processing job", i)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    }
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    jobs <- 1
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "hello world")
}

func main() {
    jobs = make(chan int, 100)
    go worker(jobs)

    http.HandleFunc("/request", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
}
```

The explanation:

**main()**

- Runs the worker in background using a go routine
- Start the service with my handler
- note that the worker in this moment is ready to receive a job

**worker()**

- it is a go routine that receives a channel
- the for loop never ends because the channel is never closed
- when a the channel contain a job, do some work (e.g. waits for 5 seconds)

**handler()**

- writes to the channel to active a job
- immediately  returns printing "hello world" to the page

the cool thing is that you can send as many requests you want and because this scenario only contains 1 worker. the next request will wait until the previous one finished.

This is awesome Go!